# Scanning a large number of files

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to scan a large number of images and I'm having some trouble. My sample folder has about 4k smallish files and I keep running into `EMFILE` errors.

I'm using `async.queue` to try to limit the number of files being processed to just 10 at a time. That should be well under the file descriptor limit, but it doesn't work. A few thousand will be scanned correctly, but I'll start getting errors for other files before the first ones are finished.

It almost seems to me like they aren't actually being queued, I'm seeing lots of "file done" and "the end" long before the data is output to the console and I'm not sure why.

I'm pretty new to Node.js so if anyone has any better ideas how to handle and do this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for any help.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypt = require('crypto');
var path = '../pictures/';
var async = require('async');

function end(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

function fileDone(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('file done');
    }
}

function scanDirectory(path, queue, callback, recursive) {

    fs.readdir(path,function(err,files) {

        if(err) {
            callback(err);
        }

            files.forEach(function(file) {

                fs.stat(path + file, function(err,stats) {

                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    if(recursive && stats && stats.isDirectory()) {

                        var newPath = path + file + '/';

                        scanDirectory(newPath, queue, callback, recursive);

                    } else if (!stats.isDirectory()) {

                        queue.push(path + file, fileDone);

                    }
                });
            });     
    });
}

var q = async.queue(function(file, callback) {
    var hash = crypt.createHash('md5');
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);

    stream.on('data',function(data) {
        hash.update(data,'utf8');
    });

    stream.on('end',function() {
        var md5 = hash.digest('hex');

        console.log(file);
        console.log(md5);
    });

    callback();
},10);

q.empty = function() {
    console.log('the end');
}

scanDirectory(path, q, end, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `async.queue`, just move your callback in your `stream.on('end'`  function, after your `console.log`

And add a `stream.on('error', callback);` to handle errors :)

Comment: OMG. So simple. So obvious. Thank you.